# Virtual keypad is hiding data elements of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an issue with a virtual keyboard.

This Soft Keyboard Covers Data Fields - and can't See what's going on.

I want to use this soft keypad and at the same time it should not become a problem to use data fields.

So how can I manage  the data fields in such cases?

Comment: Do you have your UI or form wrapped in a scrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also consider setting the following attribute on your Activity in the Android Manifest to further specify the behavior.

From here (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                   "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                   "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                   "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                   "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]
```

I find that adjustResize works better for applications contained in ScrollViews in my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Encase the layout that you already have set up within a ScrollView. This will allow the content to scroll when the software keyboard shows. Keep in mind a ScrollView has to be formatted as such.

```
<Scrollview android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!-- Your content -->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```